# How to date-format a parameter in a formatted string

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, string-formatting

Is it possible to use string formatting `string.Format("stuff happened on {0}", date)`, but also format the date using date formatting?

I could of course use `string.Format("stuff {0}", date.ToString("d"))`; however, that won't fly when I'm using `StringFormat` in a XAML binding like this:

```
<TextBlock Text={Binding SomeDate,StringFormat='{}stuff happened on {0}'} />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible using the lesser-known [optional parts of the format item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx).  Those are *alignment* and *formatString* in `index [,alignment] [:formatString]`.

So, I can answer my question using the following:

```
<TextBlock Text={Binding SomeDate,StringFormat='{}stuff happened on {0,10:d}'} />
```